# trim white space for print command in r markdown

Tags: r, r-markdown

R Markdown display unwanted space between lines when I print a character variable of a data frame with the command `print(df[[i]])`

[image]

My desired output would preserve line breaks but without white spaces between lines similar to the following. I can obtain it just using the command `print(df[[i]])` in R but I cannot manage to get it in R Markdown

```
[1] "No negative points"                                                                                                                                                                                                                              
[2] "The course was too short, not all interesting parts of the method could be covered."                                                                                                                                                             
[3] "the exercises to do at home were done together during course hours, which took too long in comparison to learning new stuff daily.  furthermore, I would have wished for even more theoretical input instead of the long R exercises (see above)"
```

**UPDATE:** The problem seems that in the intermediate latex file sometimes markdown avoid inserting  `//`. Hereunder an example of the latex code resulting from markdown

```
{[}1{]} ``good overview over underlying principles of web scraping''\\
{[}2{]} ``none''\\
{[}3{]} ``very well presented''\\
{[}4{]} ``- clear distinction between `big data' and `medium data' -
insight into what R can do in terms of webscraping'' {[}5{]} ``- a good
insight into what is possible with R w.r.t. webscraping''
```

Any help is appreciated

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: I've tried to white strip both with trimws() and the markdown option with no luck

Answer (score 0):

Given this:

````
```{r}
df <- data.frame(c("No negative points", "The course was too short, not all interesting parts of the method could be covered.", "the exercises to do at home were done together during course hours, which took too long in comparison to learning new stuff daily.  furthermore, I would have wished for even more theoretical imput instead of the long R exercises (see above)"), stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
```
````

Try using the `results` argument for an R chunk in markdown:

````
```{r, results = "asis"}
print(df[[1]])
```
````

For output like:

[image]

Comment: This work but sometimes it fails to print it on a new line. [Example](https://ibb.co/mdbhOn)

Comment: @AlbertoStefanelli - That's odd- I can't replicate that error. Can you show the code (including the r chunk arguments) that produces that output?

Comment: Update in the main post